# WatchKit: How can I implement a text shadow?

Tags: swift, text, watchkit, shadow

In my Apple Watch app, I'm trying to place text over the top of an image. I've got a group with a background image and label positioned correctly. But depending on the image, my white text can sometimes be unreadable. Dark text would have the same problem or be even worse.

Is there a way to have black text just under my white text and slightly offset?

Comment: Don't know of a way to add a drop shadow to text in watchkit but I have had good results by placing a label in a group then assigning a background image, that is a gradient, to group.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of WatchKit doesn't provide a way to "stack" or layer `WKInterfaceLabel` controls. So, the idea of including black text under the white text using a second label won't work.

You might consider rendering your drop-shadowed text as a `UIImage` in your Watch extension and using the image with a `WKInterfaceImage` control. Something like:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithText:(NSString *)text shadowBlurRadius:(CGFloat)shadowBlurRadius {

    NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = shadowBlurRadius;
    shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName    : [UIColor whiteColor],
                                  NSFontAttributeName               : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:36.0f],
                                  NSShadowAttributeName             : shadow };

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width + (2.0f * shadowBlurRadius),
                                                      size.height + (2.0f * shadowBlurRadius)),
                                           NO,
                                           2.0f);

    [text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(shadowBlurRadius, shadowBlurRadius)
       withAttributes:attributes];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Comment: NSShadow is not available on Apple Watch

Comment: You're correct that NSShadow isn't available on the Watch, but it is available on the iPhone. This code ran on the iPhone in the Watch extension for v1.